# ggplot2 put text between two violin plots in facet_grid with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-text

I have seen a number of questions related to what I'm asking, but not addressing my issue directly. I am making a panel of overlaid violin and boxplots in a facet_grid with ggplot. The data is split by a control and experimental variable and in each facet plot I simply want to put an asterisks or "ns" above and between the control and experimental group.

Here is some example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
type<- c("a", "a", "a", "a","a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
value<- as.numeric(c("9", "9.5", "9.1", "9.8", "8.8", "8.7", "8.9", "9", "9.5", "9.1", "9.8", "8.8", "8.7", "8.9"))
group<- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2")

data<-data.frame(type, value, group)
```

This code will generate a plot:

```
plot1<- ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y= value))+
  facet_grid(~type)+
  geom_violin(aes(color=group), size=0.5)+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.3, size=0.5, color="black")+
  ylim(5,11)+
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("1"="black", "2"="red"))+
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"), 
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black")
  )
```

I want an asterisks between groups 1 and 2 in each plot. Here is some dummy data for the text annotation:

```
text<- c("*", "ns")
type<- c("a", "b")
value2<- as.numeric("10.5", "10.5")

statsDf<- data.frame(text, type, value2)
```

And here is the geom_text argument I use to add the text annotations:

```
  geom_text(data=statsDf,
            size=10,
            mapping=aes(x=Inf, y=value2,
                        label = text))
```

When I add this to the plot, I get the following:

[image]

Id like the text centered in each plot, but I don't know how to define the x value to do so.

Anyone mind giving me a hand?

Comment: did you try to do this with merging dataset?

Comment: @patula, sorry I dont know what merging means.

Comment: oh sorry, I mean merge two dataset and then try plot again with same code, in this way your * and ns values probably fit in the points.

Comment: @patula that was my first attempt, didnt work. This example above is the closest I have gotten.

Comment: Try `geom_text(..., aes(x = 1.5, ...))` to center the label.

Comment: @stefan, thank you for that. Did the trick.